# How can I optimize all of these pipes?

Tags: powershell, pipe

```
get-command | where-object { $_.commandtype -eq "cmdlet" } | sort-object -property name | select-object -property name | where-object { $_.name -match "^get" } | out-file "getcommands.txt"

$content = get-content "getcommands.txt"

$content | Foreach-Object { $_.TrimEnd() } | where { $_ -match "\w" } | Out-File "getcommands.txt" -encoding Ascii

compare-object -referenceobject $(Get-Content "oldcommands.txt") -differenceobject $(Get-Content "getcommands.txt") -includeequal
```

This code retrieves all of the cmdlets which begin with "get" and compares them to a list in a text file.  It also removes excess returns and whitespace so compare actually works.

Everything works but it is pretty hard to read.  I'm just learning how to write PowerShell scripts so I'm not sure how to accomplish the same task with more elegant code.

I'm betting there is a way to do this without all the pipes.  I also wasn't able to get the output from the first line of code to output to a text file without a whole bunch of extra spaces and returns.

Answer (score 1):

I think this do the same:

```
get-command -CommandType "cmdlet" -name get*  | SELECT -expand name | 
out-file "getcommands.txt" -encoding Ascii

compare-object -referenceobject (Get-Content "oldcommands.txt") -differenceobject (Get-Content "getcommands.txt") -includeequal
```

Comment: I have one optimization to add :) use the noun param: -Noun Get

Comment: @ShayLevy Is `-verb get` ;) but I think this returns also functions and alias with verb get

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-Verb Get`?

Comment: @ShayLevy for the respect that I have for you I tried in every way to run -Noun and only after realizing that you mean -verb! lol!

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm not sure how but this method of outputting the commands doesn't have extra whitespace in the text file.

Comment: @MichaelBlazicevich What extra whitespace? This method doesn't produce any.

Comment: I was referring to the whitespace generated by my initial pipe heavy method.  I don't fully understand why my method coughed out whitespace and why this method doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got V3, this seems just a bit quicker:

```
(get-command -CommandType "cmdlet" -name get*).name |
set-content getcommands.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Filter the list of cmdlets at the source with `-verb`. Best practice is to filter as much as you can on the left side of the pipeline (closest to the source of the data)

```
get-command -verb get |where-object{$_.CommandType -eq "Cmdlet"}|select-object -expandpropertyproperty name|out-file getcommands.txt -encoding ascii
compare-object -referenceobject $(Get-Content "oldcommands.txt") -differenceobject $(Get-Content "getcommands.txt") -includeequal
```

There *should* be a way to eliminate the `Where-Object` as well with the `-CommandType` parameter for `get-command` but I cannot get it working here. I expect one of the following to work, but neither does:

```
get-command -verb get -CommandType Cmdlet
get-command -verb get -CommandType [system.management.automation.commandtypes]::Cmdlet
```

Comment: -1 the way to eliminate the `Where-Object` to filter the -CommandType is in my answer, and follows the best practice you've told.

Comment: Apparently `-commandtype` and `-verb` cannot be used together. I don't see this in the documentation though.

Comment: they are in different parameterSet name, that's why I filter with `-name get*`